# Изменить имя файла после отдачи php

Tags: php

После отдачи zip-архива пользователю нужно его имя изменить. Делаю так:

```
echo "http://site.com/modules/" . $file_name_zip;
$new_file_name_zip = md5(time()).".zip";
rename(ROOT . "modules/" . $file_name_zip, ROOT . "modules/" . $new_file_name_zip);
```

Файл переименовывается, но пользователь не успевает его получить, так как он почему-то быстрее переименовывается, чем отдаётся, и получает ошибку `failed to open stream:`

Сторона пользователя принимает его, просто скопировав себе на сервер:

```
copy($server_response, $install_zip)
```

Comment: вы отдаете пользователю всего лишь путь к файлу (даже не header Location)...ну а дальше он его скачивает с сервера, а пхп скрипт выходит. Копайте в сторону функции readfile. или делайте реализацию временных ссылок

Comment: readfile не подходит в моём случае, а что за временные ссылки?

Comment: Обычная практика - генерация ссылки, которая доступна какое то время. Переход на нее позже даст 404. выдаете ссылку с токеном, токен в базу, а ссылка на скрипт, который проверит валиден ли еще токен и если да, то отдаст файл.

Comment: Временная ссылка тоже не катит. В этом случае файл загрузится пользователю на компьютер, а мне нужно что бы он сохранялся ему на сервер.

Comment: компьютер, который копирует файл себе скачивая его с вашего сервера является клиентом по отношению к вашему серверу. И неважно десктоп ли это или другой сервер. Не нужно их рассматривать как нечто различное. в вашем примере вы всего лишь даете клиенту ссылку и тут же переименовываете, поэтому и не работает. readfile позволяет подождать пока скачает и скрыть реальный путь. можно дать ссылку на другой скрипт, где будет readfile. иначе никак нельзя узнать что файл скачан, если только клиент не сообщит об этом явно отдельным запросом.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте отдавать header с именем файла

`header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$new_file_name_zip.'"');`